# Error de permisos de carpera instalando vuejs global en npm

Tags: npm

Estoy intentando instalar el vuejs con `$ npm install -g @vue/cli` en el npm pero se para a media isntalación y me suelta esto:

> npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR!
>   errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] npm ERR!   stack:
>   npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'', npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code:
>   'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected
>   by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the
>   permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check
>   the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories,
>   or try running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator
>   (though this is not recommended). npm ERR! A complete log of this run
>   can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/facu/.npm/_logs/2019-05-13T10_24_26_577Z-debug.log

No sé donde están las carpetas a las que hace referencia, estoy trabajando desde la consola ubuntu dentro de un W10, y pongo mis proyectos en la carpeta pública, a la que ya le he quitado creo todas las restricciones.

Comment: Le estas diciendo que lo instale de forma globla con la opcion `-g` y el error te esta diciendo que no tiene permisos en `/usr/lib/node_modules`